# Sending input by onclick

Tags: javascript, forms, post

Is this possible to add to onclick the comment that is in the textarea in the same form? and how do i get it in javascript function?

```
        <form id='comments' method='post'>
        <textarea rows='8' cols='80' name='comments'></textarea> <br />
        <input type='submit' name='send' onclick='sendcomment(".$photoid.",".$mynick.",".$_POST['comments'].")' value='Wyślij'>
        </form>

 <script>   
 function sendcomment(photoid, mynick,comments){ }  
 </script>
```

Comment: Add the comment to what?

Comment: @Phillip Take a look at the onclick, i have edited it. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: So, `onclick` you want to send the comment server side?

Comment: Yea, but i am not sure how to do this thing with POST in js and also this is being sent from the same form is it even possible?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Normally you define an `<form action="handler.php" method="post">` and when someone clicks an `<input type="submit" />` inside the associated form the browser fires a request to the server and submits the form contents.  Are you saying you want to do this AJAX style?

Comment: @Phillip Yeah it also is confusing me because i am working on a small piece of code since few days and my own logic is confusing me. But its all too stupid to explain it. xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do. But I think you are over complicating this.  Define your `action` (a PHP controller to deal with the the request) and the form will be submitted by the browser when the submit button is clicked.

```
<form id='comments' action='/handler.php' method='post'>
    <textarea rows='8' cols='80' name='comments'></textarea> <br />
    <input type='submit' name='send' />
</form>
```

UPDATE:

It sounds to me like what you want to do is submit these by AJAX. I'd highly recommend you use the jQuery library to to this.

Add this to your page `<head>` tag:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Then change your form to use a `class`, rather than `id` because you can only have one `id` per name for each page. Since you are using a `while` loop you need to eliminate this issue.

```
<form class='comments' action='/handler.php' method='post'>
    <textarea rows='8' cols='80' name='comments'></textarea> <br />
    <input type='submit' name='send' />
</form>
```

Now, we need some jQuery to help us out...

```
$(document).on('submit', '.comments', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var serialized = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "handler.php",
        method: "post",
        data: serialized,
    })
    .done(function(data) {
    // take some action when the request completes
    });
});
```

This will prevent the default action of submitting the form when you click the button, then the jQuery will take over and serialize (stringify) the form data and send it to the server as an AJAX request.  Once the `.done` fires you can do more, like show the user a message that the submission was successful... maybe disable the submit button so they can't hammer the server with messages easily, etc... I really hope this helps!

Comment: I have while loop posting photographs, under every photo i have a link "comments" when i press it the popup appears and it contains this form. Now what i am trying to do is to add a comment to database to the particular photo connected with the link.
I tried to do it in milion ways but this is not working. I am working on it like 20 hours a day and just nothing. Its 5 at night already and i am so tired already

Comment: OK... expanded on my answer!

Comment: Your answer is really great sir, thank you so much for it!
But lets say after .done i want to alert this somment and it alerts "Object object". What does that mean? This is so difficult to me :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you are alerting, but the first step is to write the PHP controller (handler) to return a JSON response. That JSON response can then contain the original comment that was sent in the original ajax request.

Comment: As for the [object object] it means you are trying to alert an object, which you can't do.  Try writing it to the console, like this.  `console.log(variable)` instead. Good luck!